# How do I parse an international date string into a DateTime object? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, date, parsing, datetime

I have a couple DateTime inputs in a form, which display international format. For example, when a Canadian user selects a date it shows up as 17/03/2016. I'm trying to parse this string into a date (to make sure it's valid date and not something like "cat"), but the parsing function isn't recognizing the international dates as valid dates. *unsubscribedFrom* and *unsubscribedTo* are strings that are being passed in from the form, which I then pass into a SQL query

```
Dim unsubscribedFromDate As DateTime
Dim unsubscribedToDate As DateTime

If DateTime.TryParse(unsubscribedFrom, unsubscribedFromDate) Then
    unsubscribedFrom = unsubscribedFromDate.ToEST().ToShortDateString()
    PageSectionWhereClause &= "AND es.DateUnsubscribed >= CONVERT(DateTime, '" & unsubscribedFrom & "')" & Environment.NewLine
End If
If DateTime.TryParse(unsubscribedTo, unsubscribedToDate) Then
    unsubscribedTo = unsubscribedToDate.ToEST().ToShortDateString()
    PageSectionWhereClause &= "AND es.DateUnsubscribed >= CONVERT(DateTime, '" & unsubscribedTo & "')" & Environment.NewLine
End If
```

When unsubscribedFrom = "17/03/2016", DateTime.TryParse fails.

NOTE: My code needs to handle international AND non-international dates, it's possible to get both.

Comment: You arent going to be able to allow users to enter dates in any fashion they choose without trying to parse for every single culture in existence. (`7/8` is legal in Can, US and UK, but means something very different). Specify a format and then use TryParseExact to test them.

Comment: `it's possible to get both.`  then it is 100% likely that you will incorrectly convert dates 12 days out of every month.  Swapping `July 8` for `August 7` for example

Answer (score 1):

Generally, never use `DateTime.Parse` or `DateTime.TryParse` - because they default to using your user account's default date formatting - if you're in the US then that's `MM/dd/yyyy` (when pretty much the entire rest of the world uses `dd/MM/yyyy`).

If you know beforehand what format they're using you should use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`.

```
DateTime value = DateTime.ParseExact("dd/MM/yyy", input);
```

If you know the user is from a particular country but unsure of the format then specify an explicit `CultureInfo`:

```
DateTime value = DateTime.Parse( CultureInfo.GetCulture("en-CA"), input);
```

Comment: I do not know which country any particular user is from. They can be from anywhere

Comment: @user3784238 If this is data from a web-form it might be an idea to accept a date as separate, explicit day, month and year components instead of a single textbox for a date value. You could also try to detect a user's language and date-formatting options from their `Accept-Language` header, though that's unreliable (e.g. if an American user was using a computer in a Canadian library).